# Output in scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd()

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd.html#scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd) and I can't for the life of me figure out the outputs.  Does anyone have any advice here?

Look at this simple sample program:

```
import scipy
scipy.__version__
# '0.14.0'
import numpy as np
print scipy.stats.binned_statistic_dd([np.ones(10), np.ones(10)], np.arange(10), 'count', bins=3)
#(array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
#       [  0.,  10.,   0.],
#       [  0.,   0.,   0.]]), 
# [array([ 0.5       ,  0.83333333,  1.16666667,  1.5       ]), 
# array([ 0.5       ,  0.83333333,  1.16666667,  1.5       ])], 
# array([12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]))
```

So the documentation claims the outputs are:

> statistic : ndarray, shape(nx1, nx2, nx3,...) The values of the
>   selected statistic in each two-dimensional bin
>
> edges : list of
>   ndarrays A list of D arrays describing the (nxi + 1) bin edges for
>   each dimension
>
> binnumber : 1-D ndarray of ints This assigns to each
>   observation an integer that represents the bin in which this
>   observation falls. Array has the same length as values.

In the example the statistic makes good sence, I asked for the 'count' and got 10, there are 10 elements all in that same bin.  Edges makes good sense too, the data to be over was a dimension 2 and I wanted 3 bins so I gotout 4 edges that are reasonable.

Then the question the binnumber makes no sense to me at all, `array([12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12])`, there are indeed 10 numbers the same length and the data inputted, `np.arange(10)`, but number 12 makes no sense at all.  What am I missing.  12 is not an unravel index over the bins turned into a multi D array, since there are 3 bins in each dimension I could see numbers up to 9.  What is 12 telling me?

Comment: For what it's worth in the 1d case it makes sense `scipy.stats.binned_statistic(np.ones(10), np.arange(10), 'count', bins=3)
(array([  0.,  10.,   0.]), array([ 0.5       ,  0.83333333,  1.16666667,  1.5       ]), array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]))`

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in `binnumbers` are an unraveled index of bins that include an extra
set of "out of range" bins.

In this example,

```
In [40]: hst, edges, bincounts = binned_statistic_dd([np.ones(10), np.ones(10)], None, 'count', bins=3)

In [41]: hst
Out[41]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,  10.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

the bins are numbered as follows:

```
  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14 
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  | 19
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 20  | 21  | 22  | 23  | 24
```

The "out of range" bins are not included in `hst`; the data in `hst` corresponds to bin numbers
6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17 and 18.  That's why all the values in `bincounts` are 12:

```
In [42]: bincounts
Out[42]: array([12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12])
```

You can use the `range` argument to force the counts into the outer bins. For example,
by setting the ranges of the coordinates to be [2, 3] and [0, 0.5], so all the values in the
first coordinate are left of their range and all the values in the second coordinate are
to the right of their range, all the points end up in the upper right outer bin, which is
bin index 4:

```
In [51]: binned_statistic_dd([np.ones(10), np.ones(10)], None, 'count', bins=3, range=[[2,3],[0,0.5]])
Out[51]: 
(array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]),
 [array([ 2.        ,  2.33333333,  2.66666667,  3.        ]),
  array([ 0.        ,  0.16666667,  0.33333333,  0.5       ])],
 array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]))
```

Comment: Ahh thanks much, we should put this answer as a suggestion into the scipy docs.